# How can i remove a column from table using rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-migrations

It is easily possible to remove a column using rails migration.

```
class SomeClass < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    remove_column :table_name, :column_name
  end
end
```

I want to know if there is any way to remove a column from table using console.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

You can run the code in the `up` method directly in `rails console`:

```
>> ActiveRecord::Migration.remove_column :table_name, :column_name
```

If you already have a migration file such as "`db/migrate/20130418125100_remove_foo.rb`", you can do this:

```
>> require "db/migrate/20130418125100_remove_foo.rb"
>> RemoveFoo.up
```

If you just want to do `rake db:migrate`, try this:

```
>> ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate "db/migrate"
```

Comment: I want to perform it if i am not having any migration file.  remove_column :table_name, :column_name does not work in console. It says: NoMethodError: undefined method `remove_column' for main:Object

Comment: `ActiveRecord::Migration.remove_column :table_name, :column_name`     This worked great!!

Comment: You may have just saved my life.  Lol ok that's a little overly dramatic, but srsly, _thank you_