# Calling a database script from a rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Ruby on Rails application (ruby 1.8.7 ; rails 2.3.18). I have a customised **rake task (basically a ruby program**) which compares two arrays, and then stores their difference in a third array (arr3 = arr1 - arr2). In the application there is a user model. And I have a database script that suspends (deletes) users from the model/db. So I want to call this database script from the rake task after the `arr3` is created. I want to run this script until all the elements in `arr3` are deleted. The arrays give the difference between two lists of users.

Can anyone guide me on this? How can I call a database script from a rake task? Anything on this will be of great help.

The rake file is as below:

```
namespace :db do
arr1 = Array.new 
arr2 = Array.new 
arr3 = Array.new

desc "load data from csv"
task :load_is_data do
  require 'fastercsv'
  CSV.foreach("C:/Sites/rails_project/demo_app/list1.csv") do |row|
arr1 << row[0]
  end

 CSV.foreach("C:/Sites/rails_project/demo_app/list2.csv") do |row|
arr2 << row[0]
  end

  arr3 = arr1-arr2 
  puts "Inactive: #{arr3}"

 #CODE TO BE ADDED, TO CALL DATABASE-SCRIPT

 end
end
```

Thanks,
Bhargav

Comment: Maybe you could have a look at this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16074630/how-can-i-remove-a-column-from-table-using-rails-console

Comment: I do not want to remove an entire column from the database. Just want to delete some entries by using the db script.

Comment: Why do you need to call a database script? Are you not using ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 0):

you can use any below gems.

```
gem "populator", "~> 1.0.0"
gem 'faker'
gem "random_data", "~> 1.6.0"
```

Code will be something like this.

```
admin = AdminUser.create :email => 'xxxxxx@gmail.com', :password => 'xxxx1234', :password_confirmation => 'xxxx1234', :role => 'SuperAdmin', :name => 'SuperAdmin'
  puts 'SuperAdmin created: ' << admin.email



      10.times do |index|
        User.create! :fname => Random.firstname,
          :lname => Random.lastname,
          :email => Random.email,
          :password => 'dcs1234',
          :password_confirmation => 'dcs1234'
      end
```

Comment: Hi Pravin,
          
          I am sorry. I could not understand your soln. I mean what will these gems do ? Also why i need to create a superuser or a superadmin ? Is there a thread/link where i can look for better understanding of your concept ? I basically wanted to know how i can call a database script (existing) from a rake task, so that it can iterate through the elements of the array and perform the desired action.

Thanks